# How to make Starchat Beta to generate code/chat instead of line completions

Tags: huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I deployed StarChat Beta to SageMaker using the script I am not able to get StarChat to output code. It only does some autocomplete.
But, as per [text](https://huggingface.co/HuggingFaceH4/starchat-beta) - StarChat is a series of language models that are trained to act as helpful coding assistants.
Deployment and inference script from Huggingface:

```
import json
import sagemaker
import boto3
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel, get_huggingface_llm_image_uri

try:
    role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
except ValueError:
    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    role = iam.get_role(RoleName='sagemaker_execution_role')['Role']['Arn']

# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'HuggingFaceH4/starchat-beta',
    'SM_NUM_GPUS': json.dumps(4)
}



# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    image_uri=get_huggingface_llm_image_uri("huggingface",version="1.0.3"),
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.g5.12xlarge",
    container_startup_health_check_timeout=300,
  )
  
# send request
predictor.predict({
    "inputs": "How can I write a Python function to generate the nth Fibonacci number?",
})
```

This outputs:

```
[{'generated_text': "How can I write a Python function to generate the nth Fibonacci number?<|end|>\n<|assistant|>\nHere's an example of a Python function that generates the nth Fibonacci number"}]
```

As we can see the output indicates that the model is not doing code recommendation/interactive chat, but it is doing line completion.
And I verified this when I ran:

```
predictor.predict(
{
"inputs": "def sum(a,b):"
})
```

It returns

```
[
{
"generated_text": "def sum(a,b):\n    return a+b\n\ndef diff(a,b):\n    return a-b\n"
}
```

Is there any parameter that I should add something I need to change in order for StarChat to give complete code and act as a chat assistant instead of give line completions?